# Memory leak when use AudioQueueNewInput

Tags: ios, memory

I'm using `AQRecorder` copied from *SpeakHere* demo.

```
mRecordFormat is defined in AQRecorder.h: CAStreamBasicDescription  mRecordFormat;
```

It turned out that there is a memory leak in method `AQRecorder::StartRecord`

Here is the code Instrument pointed to:

```
AudioQueueNewInput(&mRecordFormat,......
```

I checked through `AQRecoder.mm`, but couldn't find any code that releases `mRecordFormat`.
My question is: do I need to write some code to release `mRecordFormat`? Since I downloaded *SpeakHere* demo from Apple website, I don't think they may forget to release `mRecordFormat`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to a `AudioQueueRef` and dispose it using `AudioQueueDispose` when you are finished.

#### Example

```
AudioQueueRef audio_queue;

OSStatus err = AudioQueueNewInput(&format_,
                                  &HandleInputBufferStatic,
                                  this,
                                  NULL,
                                  kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                                  0,
                                  &audio_queue);
                                    
OSStatus err = AudioQueueDispose(audio_queue, true);
```

Comment: hi, reecon,I already disposed audio queue when finished record: AudioQueueDispose(mQueue, true);